# Search and open file from within Vim

Tags: bash, find, vim

I have a pair of Bash functions:

```
function ff() { find . -path -o -name $@ -print; }
function fvim() { ff "$@" -exec vim {} \;; }
```

Which is helpful for finding a file and opening it right away in Vim. What I'd like to do is either extend this or create a similar function which I can call from within Vim (searching from my current directory, probably just using 'ff') to open the found file in a new buffer of that Vim instance.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

With Vim alone:

```
:set path=.,,**
:find foo.txt
```

The filename can't contain wildcards, but `:find` does have TAB completion.

Alternatively there are many excellent plugins that can do that and a lot more, f.i. [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim), [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim), or [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim).